# A complicated sum in R data.table that involves looking at other columns

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a data table where each value for variables `v1` and `v2` has an associated "type", coded in a separate column. Here is a MWE:

```
X <- data.table(id = 1:5, group = c(1,1,2,2,2), v1 = c(10,12,14,16,18), type_v1 = c("t1","t2","t1","t1","t2"), v2 = c(3,NA,NA,7,8), type_v2 = c("t2", "", "", "t3","t3"))
print(X)
   id group v1 type_v1 v2 type_v2
1:  1     1 10      t1  3      t2
2:  2     1 12      t2 NA        
3:  3     2 14      t1 NA        
4:  4     2 16      t1  7      t3
5:  5     2 18      t2  8      t3
```

I want to sum up the values in columns `v1` and `v2` for each type by the variable `group`. The desired output is:

```
   group v1 type_v1  v2 type_v2  v3 type_v3
1:     1 10      t1  15      t2  NA
2:     2 30      t1  18      t2  15      t3
```

There are a lot of different "types", and not all types occur in all groups. I may need to create variables `v3`, `v4`, etc. (note how in my example an extra column appeared to accommodate the t1, t2, and t3 in group 2).

My data is currently in the long format. I would prefer not to reshape it to the wide format if possible. I am interested in the solutions that do not involve creating columns "t1", "t2" etc. This is because "t1", "t2" and "t3" are actually very long strings.

Edit: typo in desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `melt` your data to long format

```
library(data.table)
X1 <-
  melt(
    X,
    id.vars = "group",
    
    # we melt multiple value vars simultaneously,
    # those starting with "v" and those starting 
    # with "type_v" followed by 1 or more digit
    measure.vars = patterns(c("^v\\d+$", "^type_v\\d+$")),
    value.name = c("value", "type")
  )
X1
#     group variable value type
# 1:     1        1     10   t1
# 2:     1        1     12   t2
# 3:     2        1     14   t1
# 4:     2        1     16   t1
# 5:     2        1     18   t2
# 6:     1        2      3   t2
# 7:     1        2     NA     
# 8:     2        2     NA     
# 9:     2        2      7   t3
#10:     2        2      8   t3
```

Aggregate the data, excluding empty strings from 'type' column

```
tmp <- X1[type!="", .("v" = sum(value)), by=.(group, type)]
tmp
#   group type  v
#1:     1   t1 10
#2:     1   t2 15
#3:     2   t1 30
#4:     2   t2 18
#5:     2   t3 15
```

And finally reshape to wide format again

```
out <- dcast(tmp, group ~ rowid(group), value.var = c("v", "type")) 
out
#   group v_1 v_2 v_3 type_1 type_2 type_3
#1:     1  10  15  NA     t1     t2   <NA>
#2:     2  30  18  15     t1     t2     t3
```

---

If you need the column order to be `v_1 | type_1 | v_2 ...` you can use `setcolorder`

```
tmp2 <- setdiff(names(out), "group")

# create a vector based on the order of the numeric part of 'tmp2'
idx <- order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", tmp2)))
setcolorder(out, c("group", tmp2[idx]))
out
#   group v_1 type_1 v_2 type_2 v_3 type_3
#1:     1  10     t1  15     t2  NA   <NA>
#2:     2  30     t1  18     t2  15     t3
```